# Different Global object in nodejs vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm going through the examples provided in [You Don't know JS series - this and Object prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md). I changed the code slightly and tested it on both Chrome and Node Js. There was a difference in the output. So here's the code:

```
function foo(num) {
// keep track of how many times `foo` is called
    this.count++;
}

var count = 9999;
var i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i > 5) {
        foo( i );
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Chrome( 73.0.3683.75 )
10003

NodeJS(v6.10.2)
9999

From what I understand, in foo() `this` refers to the global object as the function is called directly. Consequently, `this.count` refers to count variable on the global object. So when 'this.count++' executes, it actually causes a new count variable to be created on global object(window in case of Chrome) and increments the same.

What I am confused about is that the behavior is different in case of NodeJs. If I slightly modify the code as below for checking the value of count on global variable in node, I see that it has a value of NaN.
Modified code for NodeJs

```
function foo(num) {
    this.count++;
}

var count = 9999;
var i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i > 5) {
        foo( i );
    }
}
console.log(count);
console.log(global.count);
```

Output

```
9999
NaN
```

So, I'd want to understand why do we have 2 different behavior in Chrome and NodeJs.

Also, Kyle says that the answer for below question will be found in Chapter 2, 
"How was it global, and why did it end up NaN instead of some proper count value?" (see Chapter 2)"
But Chapter 2 of the book does not offer any explanation to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to globals with `this` is a bad practice because it's unknown in which scope a script will be evaluated. The only reliable way to access a global is to use indirect evaluation (until [`globalThis`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global) becomes available which currently can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/ljharb/globalThis)).

For Node:

```
(0, eval)('this') === global
```

For browsers (can be disabled with CSP):

```
(0, eval)('this') === window
```

> From what I understand, in foo() this refers to the global object as the function is called directly.

This is the actual problem. Node script is evaluated in module scope, `var count` creates local variable in the scope of [module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper), while `this` refers to `module.exports`.

Comment: Why does count have NaN in case of NodeJs?

Comment: Because it's not `count` but `this.count`, and `this === module.exports`. `module.exports.count === undefined`, and `undefined++` results in `NaN`.

Comment: Since, `this === module.exports` and `module.export !== global`. Would it be correct to say the above code creates count variable on the global object even in case of Node JS?

Comment: No, because `var count` is local variable in Node, `module.exports` object is local, too. It would be global everywhere only if it were `(0, eval)('var count = 999')` and `(0, eval)('this.count++')`.

Comment: So, when Kyle says that "In fact, were she to dig deeper, she would find that she had accidentally created a global variable count", is it true only when the code executes in browser?

Comment: Yes. Because in Node it executes in module function and not in global scope, I mentioned this in the answer. This wouldn't be true for a browser either if the code were executed in ES module.

Comment: If you are fine, I will raise an issue on their github repo, to add a note mentioning these details.

Comment: Sure. It likely needs to mention that the code is supposed to be evaluated in global scope and not in modular environment. FWIW, there wouldn't such problems if you were testing this in Node console.